# Geonames querying for parks in Puerto Rico or US Virgin Islands

Tags: geonames

I thought these were US-related entities.

When I make this kind of a query to geoNames, I get nothing back.

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=genadinik&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=CR&maxRows=10

Does anyone know how to query for parks in these territories?

Comment: As this is the fourth question you've asked along similar lines, might I suggest you look at the files that are on the GeoNames website? The file you're looking for is http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt Which gives you all the country codes. I'll leave choosing the right country code for the Maldives as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Mersey In response to your observation, I have merged the three most similar questions: they all concern identifying the correct country codes for park queries.

Comment: According to the documentation http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html the country names are ISO-3166 http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm

Comment: Since your question about the [Maldives](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10072/986) was closed, let me note here that MA is the code for Morocco; the code for the Maldives is MV. Here is a [friendlier link](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm) to the ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puerto Rico isn't included under the 'US' label (likely due to its unincorporated status), it can instead by found by changing the country to 'PR':

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=genadinik&country=PR&style=full&maxRows=10

Answer (score 2):

The country code for American Samoa is AS. Try something like this:  http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=genadinik&country=AS&maxRows=1000